# Tell computer to use my dll files

Tags: dll, batch-file, environment-variables

I need to write a batch file which gets the path for a folder(e.g. lib) located in the current directory of the batch file and tell my computer to use my dll files located in there.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: `tell my computer to use my dll files located in there` - Can you elaborate? How exactly are you going to use them?

Comment: I suppose the only thing i need is to only Add my dll files from a specific folder to java.library.path. I have already done that by hand and everything is working. What I need is to send a package to someone but i do not want to tell the guy to go in this folder get this dll files find your java path and put them there...

Comment: So you need to move or copy your Dll's to a different folder?

Comment: exactly. but i need to now java.library.path as well. So as you said i only need to copy my dll to java.library.path...

Comment: Ok, but what is `java.library.path`? I don't use Java, so I have no idea! :)

Comment: java.library.path is used by Java to find native libraries (dlls on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by changing the approach. Now I add my library into a given folder and then add its path to PATH environment variables by a batch file. Then run my exe file.